# How do I position AdMob ad above the Tabbar?

Tags: iphone, ipad, admob, tabbar, ios4

I've gotten the latest version of the iOS code for AdMob.  It is working fine, but the ad shows up under the tabbar I have.  How do I move the ad up above the bar?  Here's my relevant code:

```
#import "InformationViewController.h"


@implementation InformationViewController

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Create a view of the standard size at the bottom of the screen.

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) 
    {
        /* run something specific for the iPad */
        bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc]
                       initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,
                                                self.view.frame.size.height -
                                                GAD_SIZE_300x250.height,
                                                GAD_SIZE_300x250.width,
                                                GAD_SIZE_300x250.height)];
    } 
    else
    {
        /* run something specific for the iPhone */
        bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc]
                       initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,
                                                self.view.frame.size.height -
                                                GAD_SIZE_320x50.height,
                                                GAD_SIZE_320x50.width,
                                                GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)];
    }

    // Specify the ad's "unit identifier." This is your AdMob Publisher ID.
    bannerView_.adUnitID = MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID;

    // Let the runtime know which UIViewController to restore after taking
    // the user wherever the ad goes and add it to the view hierarchy.
    bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
    [self.view addSubview:bannerView_];

    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad.
    [bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
}
```

And my header file -

```
#import "GADBannerView.h"

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface InformationViewController : UIViewController {

    GADBannerView *bannerView_;

}

@end
```

Comment: So I've seen one recommendation to use a TableView, but I do not want to use a TableView for this App.  Are there any other options?

Comment: Well, I continue to research this one, since I am not seeing much by the way of answer here.. I will post one if I find it.

Comment: I am switching to iAd to see if I can resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this;

```
bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc]
                       initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,
                                                100.0 -
                                                GAD_SIZE_320x50.height,
                                                GAD_SIZE_320x50.width,
                                                GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)];
```

use any other number below of 100 to move the banner up. Hope this work for you!